# PaintComponent() method gets stuck after second run

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I am currently working on a brick breaker game and have run into an issue with the paintComponent method. The first time repaint is called (to invoke paintComponent) everything works fine, but the second time it is called the program gets stuck on the last line of paintComponent.

Below is code and screenshots of the issue I am having.

MyPanel Code:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static Model model;
    public MyPanel(){
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }


    public void updateModel(Model modelArg){
        model = modelArg;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        draw(g2);
    }

    //Draw each game component
    public static void draw(Graphics2D g2){

        draw(g2, g, model.getPaddle());
        draw(g2, g, model.getBall());
        draw(g2, g, model.getBrickArray());
    }

    //Draw Paddle
    public static void draw(Graphics2D g2, Paddle paddle){
        Rectangle paddleImage = new Rectangle(paddle.getX(),paddle.getY(), paddle.getWidth(),paddle.getHeight());
        g2.setColor(paddle.getColor());
        g2.fill(paddleImage);
        g2.draw(paddleImage);
    }

    //Draw Circle
    public static void draw(Graphics2D g2, Ball ball){
        Double x = Double.valueOf(ball.getX());
        Double y = Double.valueOf(ball.getY());
        Double height = Double.valueOf(ball.getHeight());
        Double width = Double.valueOf(ball.getWidth());

        Ellipse2D ballImage = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, height, width);
        g2.setColor(ball.getColor());
        g2.fill(ballImage);
        g2.draw(ballImage);
    }

    //Draw Bricks
    public static void draw(Graphics2D g2, Brick[] brickArray){
        for(int i = 0; i<brickArray.length; i++){
            Brick brick = brickArray[i];

            if(!brick.isDestroyed()) {
                Rectangle brickImage = new Rectangle(brick.getX(), brick.getY(), brick.getWidth(), brick.getHeight());
                g2.setColor(brick.getColor());
                //g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.fill(brickImage);
                g2.draw(brickImage);
            }
            else{

                g2.clearRect(brick.getX(), brick.getY(), brick.getWidth(), brick.getHeight());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the View class that creates the MyPanel object and calls repaint

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    private static Model model;
    private MyPanel panel;

    public View() {
        model = new Model();
    }

    //Creates Frame object
    //Creates MyPanel object
    //Paints MyPanel object
    public void createFrame(Model modelArg) {
        model = modelArg;
        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(500, 550);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Breakout Ball");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        panel = new MyPanel();

        panel.updateModel(model);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void updateView(Model modelArg) {
        model = modelArg;
        revalidate();
        panel.updateModel(model);
        panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

And here is the controller

```
public class Controller {
    private Model model;
    public View view;

    public Controller(Model model, View view){
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
        initView();

        int i = 10;
        while(i>0){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    doCycle();
                }});
                model.getBrickArray()[0].setDestroyed(true);
            i--;
        }
    }

    public void initView(){
        model.createGamePieces();
        //view.initGamePieces(model.getPaddle());
        view.createFrame(model);

    }

    public void doCycle(){
        view.updateView(model);
    }

}
```

[Image of debugger when the code gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF9Hx.png)

If the above image is not showing up, it displays how in the debugger under variables it just says "The application is running" and there are no options to step over, step into etc.

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know!

Edit:
I just cleaned up the code to make it a minimal reproducible example per request. I wasn't sure how much to remove because I'm not exactly sure the scope of what is causing this problem, so I leaned towards removing less code.

Thank you,
Jon

Comment: Do you realize that Graphics2D is a subclass of g?  So you only need to pass g2 do the methods.  The method of g will still be available.  And please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You are missing some classes (and no don't post them).   I would suggest  you look for  some condition where you are tying up the Event Dispatch Thread causing your program to lock up.  If you were recursively calling methods with in the painting process you would eventually get a stack overflow.  So it may be some other loop that is tying up the EDT.  With so much code and it being incomplete, that is the best I can offer.  I have better luck sprinkling in print statements at key points (entering and exiting methods) to help narrow down the location.

Comment: Hi WSJ, I added SOP.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) throughout my code and true was printed in every instance. I was having a problem with the EDT earlier, but adding Swing.Utilities.invokeLater() to the Controller when calling doCycle() fixed the problem. Is this enough to determine there are no problems with the Event Dispatch Thread, or is there something else I can look for? Thank you, Jon

Comment: That just means your running in the EDT.  So somewhere you must be doing something to tie up processing. For example if you have two flags waiting for each other to be set, then you will have lock up and the EDT will never return.  You said it worked the first time but later locked up.  So whatever action you took with your game during that time probably contributed to the problem.

Comment: Also, if you have other threads depending on some booleans or other flags, you should probably declare them volatile to ensure the threads are reading the current value.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out if there are any threading issues but I am getting nowhere. As far as I know I do not have other threads dependent on other flags, but my experience with threading is extremely limited so i could be wrong. One other clue is that the updateView() method from View is being called 10 times, which calls panel.repaint() in each call, but panel.repaint() is only invoked after the 10 calls.

Comment: If I remove the call for repaint(), then paintComponent() isn't called that last time, so the repaint() call after the 10 updateView() calls isn't a spontaneous call

Comment: I think i'm just going to do without the explicit repaint() call, if I add a mouseListener and move the paddle on each click, the graphic works fine.

Comment: Why are you still extending JFrame?